# Ideas for building vulnerabilities into your site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a programming challenge that would require developers to hack into the MVC site I create.  The idea is obviously to teach them about preventing these types of attacks.

The current idea I have is to build multiple vulnerabilities into the site - but the second vulnerability would require the first to be completed, etc.  So I was thinking the first could be a sql injection attack, the second would require a modified GET request, etc.

Exploiting the final vulnerability would reveal a specific piece of information which is proof that you have completed the entire challenge.

This will not be deployed on a public site - it's simply a learning tool for developers at my company.  I'm not looking for MVC-specific vulnerabilities - I'm simply using MVC because it allows me to work with the 'raw' HTML.

Any ideas on the different vulnerabilities I can use?

Comment: Excellent.  When someone breaks in they can then hijack the site, change the passwords, deface the pages and use the thing as a botnet node to send spam email.  Cool idea.  Why not just donate the computer to a botnet?  That's where it will wind up.

Comment: Teaching is normally done by someone who has knowledge to impart, I'd start with the vulnerabilities you know well and I'm sure you'll get suggestions from your 'students' for more. Asking a question here that could be construed as a thinly veiled attempt to discover potential vulnerabilities in ASP.NET MVC might not garner the responses you are looking for. It is also more of a security question than a programming question, when you have the vulnerabilities and are looking for help implementing them then this will undoubtedly be the best place to look for help.

Comment: Most folks fishing for a spam host will write a simple script to break your vulnerabilities in order.  They'll run that script from a cron job, breaking into your system each time you clean them out and restarting their spam engine.  Check your logs carefully, it should happen within a few minutes of you making this great resource available.

Comment: Wow, you guys are being a little negative in my opinion, but let me expand.  This will not be a public-facing site.  It's only internal - for the devs at my company.  I know quite a few web vulnerabilities, but it's pretty difficult to use some of them in this context since I want to create a vulnerability that exposes data.  I can't really use a Cross-site scripting attack here, how would that work?  I'm NOT looking for MVC specific stuff, I'm looking for general web stuff.

Comment: @S.Lott: That's pretty paranoid :-) You're right that one should be careful with this sort of thing not to expose any unwanted vulnerabilities--but then, you always have to be careful not to expose any unwanted vulnerabilities :-). However, with adequate precautions, this site needn't be in any way useful to spammers/botherders. For instance - I would start by running it in a VM, and using firewall rules (outside the VM) so that only incoming TCP connections on port 80 could reach the VM. That way, even if someone completely takes over the VM, the worst they can do is serve HTTP requests...

Comment: @Jaco Pretorius: Please expand by UPDATING your question.  Please do not add yet more comments to a question which you own.  And.  I'm not being "paranoid".  This is what actually happens to unprotected systems.  You can take all the precautions you want, but if you allow hijacking it will be hijacked -- and quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take some inspiration from [something similar from Google](http://jarlsberg.appspot.com/). They go through a number of types of vulnerability, and for each type explain how to exploit and prevent that kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go through the [OWASP top ten](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) and just do the opposite of each :)